# VBA For Loop Only Altering One Sheet

Tags: vba, excel, for-loop

I'm trying to alter the values in a range of cells for specifically named worksheets only.

The workbook I am editing has around 95 sheets, and I only want to change the sheets with the period actual information (named P1W1, P1W2 etc, up to P12W5).

When i execute the below it only alters the first sheet and then exits the macro.

Any help is much appreciated

```
    Option Explicit

Public Sub periodclear()

Dim ws As Worksheet
Dim r As Range

On Error Resume Next

Set r = Range("c10:i30")

For Each ws In Worksheets
    If ws.Name Like ("P#W#") Or ws.Name Like ("P##W#") Then

       r.Value = ""

    End If

Next ws

End Sub
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this. Your `r` was defined only in terms of one sheet so needs to be brought inside the loop.

```
Public Sub periodclear()

Dim ws As Worksheet

For Each ws In Worksheets
    If ws.Name Like ("P#W#") Or ws.Name Like ("P##W#") Then
        ws.Range("c10:i30").ClearContents
    End If
Next ws

End Sub
```

Comment: CallumDA - they do work, # is a wildcard for a numeric, both that and ? were returning results when I tried Debug.print ws.name